# Update the particular row of a GWT cellTable

Tags: gwt, smartgwt

I'm trying to update the particular row of a cellTable without loading the page when clicking a button, which is in the same row.

I just want to update the Column1 which is a TextColumn. I want to Change the text of the particular column.

Can anyone help me?

Thanks in Advance,
Gnik

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/7109021/787660

When you use the ListDataAdapter and add your row like in the example using the ListWrapper (don't be scared, you use it like a List-Object) the refresh is automatically triggered.

Comment: Actually i need to change the text of column1. Can you give me an example?


Thanks in advance,
Gnik

Answer (score 4):

If you want to redraw the whole row, you can use:

```
celltable.redrawRow(absIndex);
```

But if you want to update a single cell and performance is important you could do this in a child class of CellTable

```
public void updateCellContent(int absRowIndex, int cellIndex, String innerHtml) {
    TableRowElement tr = getChildElement(absRowIndex);
    if (tr != null) {
        TableCellElement td = tr.getCells().getItem(cellIndex);
        if (td != null) {
            td.setInnerHTML(innerHtml);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I suppose you use a ListDataProvider to store as it is used in the showcase example [here](http://gwt.google.com/samples/Showcase/Showcase.html#!CwCellTable).

In that case you just have to up change the data in the ListDataProvider and when its done just call

```
cellTable.redraw();
```

And don't worry the table doesn't flicker when doing that :)

Comment: you don't need redraw, it's overkill. The ListWrapper handles this case, see following example...